# How to create a ranking logic/formula with multiple metrics in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a big list of pages for a website that I need to write content for. To prioritise the work, I want to come up with a ranking based on 4 metrics, which are:

**Keyword Difficulty:**  The estimated difficulty to rank high in a Search Engines' results for the keyword people search for. A lower number is better:

0-10 Easy, 11-30 Medium, 31-70 Hard, 71+ Very Hard

**Search Volume:**  The average amount of times a keyword gets searched by users each month.  Higher is better.

**Pages Current Avg position:**  The avg position the relevant page on the website is currently ranked in when users are searching for the keyword on a search engine. A lower number is better, as position 1 is the top of the first pages search results and there are generally 10 results per page, so  1-10 is on page one, 11-19 is page two, etc.

**Conversation Rate:** The rate at which visitors convert on each page to a take an action.  Higher is better.

My data looks like so:

[image]

How can I use those 4 metrics to come up with some kind of ranking to prioritise working on the pages?

Looking to prioritise keywords that have a high search volume, a difficulty that isn't too hard, a higher conversation rate and where a page is already ranking higher in avg position. (Not necessarily in that order)

Comment: Assign a weight to each value and merge them in a helper column then sort based on that

Comment: What's the best way to merge them?